# Whitelist for OpenID on android

Tags: android, openid, google-openid, google-oauth

I want to authenticate my application's user, in order to know what they could access.
I have decided to use the authentification method provided by google.
But, as my application need to stay private, I would like to be able to give to google a whitelist of user that can access to my application.

Do you know how i can create such whitelist ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Google to do that.  After authenticating, Google will provide the email address of the person who just authenticated so you can put the whitelist inside your own service and reject those that don't match in whatever way you desire.